# Excel VBA isfiltered not Working in chart

Tags: excel, vba, colors, excel-charts

With VBA I often create 2 complementary line charts in an excel Spreadsheet. Typically, the 2 charts have the same number of SeriesCollections, and every ch1.SeriesCollection(i) (SC(I)) is related related to ch2.SeriesCollection(i), but not the same chart. It is desirable for the plot colors to be the same for each i in both chart. It is also desirable to be able to selectively remove and restore using VBA selective plots (e.g., all i values except i = 2) using isfiltered as in VBA code below.

All the code below works as desired, except the last statement: "ch1.SeriesCollection(2).IsFiltered = False". The previous statement "= True" removes (from view) SeriesCollection(2) from the chart, and the "= False" should restore it for view. But it does not. And I can't find a solution. Guidance to solution will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub Charts1()
    Dim sh1, chr1, chr2 As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh1 = ActiveSheet
    sh1.Cells.Clear
    sh1.ChartObjects.Delete
    sh1.Range("B1:D1") = [{"A","B","C"}]
    sh1.Range("A2:A3") = [{"1";"2"}]
    sh1.Range("A2:A3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A12"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    sh1.Range("B2:D2").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    sh1.Range("B3:B12").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C*1.02"
    sh1.Range("C3:C12").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C*1.04"
    sh1.Range("D3:D12").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C*1.06"
    sh1.Range("A1:A12,B1:D1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    sh1.Range("B2:D12").NumberFormat = "#,##0.000"
    
    Set ch1 = sh1.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Chart
    ch1.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Data!$A$1:$D$12")
    ch1.Parent.Left = 50
    ch1.Parent.Top = 200
    Set ch2 = sh1.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Chart
    ch2.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Data!$A$1:$D$12")
    ch2.Parent.Left = 450
    ch2.Parent.Top = 200
    ch1.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ch1.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    ch1.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    ch2.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    ch2.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 255)
    ch2.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 255)
    c1s1color = ch1.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
    For i = 1 To ch2.SeriesCollection.Count
        ch2.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = ch1.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
        ch2.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = ch1.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
        ch2.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = ch1.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
    Next i
    ch1.SeriesCollection(2).IsFiltered = True
    ch1.SeriesCollection(2).IsFiltered = False
End sub
```

Comment: Comment out `On Error Resume Next`. Does any line throw an error? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: The code above runs without error if the "On error resume next" statement is removed.   And the last statement runs with no error, but the results are not correct. A habit that is not needed in this code. Sorry.

Comment: I think I found a solution. I changed all "SeriesCollection(i)" to "FullSeriesCollection(i)" and it works. It appears that "FullSeriesCollection" is not available in VBA 2010, so perhaps updating ranges would be the only solution.